# Ao tentar acessar o repository com.sun.faces.context.AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl handlePartialResponseError

Tags: java, jsf, spring

Galera, estou passando por um problema aqui, e não consigo resolver. Já procurei nos foruns, mas também nao vi soluções. Alguem dá esse help please?

O erro acontece quando tento salvar o fomulário com os dados do usuário. Achei que pudesse estar mandando o objeto usuário nulo, porém já verifiquei que não é isso.

Já verifiquei muitas vezes para ver se não esqueci de inicializar alguma variável de instância ou objeto, porém também não achei nada de errado.

O stracktrace indica que o erro está na linha 27, na chamada serviceUser.addUser(user);

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at br.com.jamming.controller.RegisterUserMB.save(RegisterUserMB.java:27)
```

Alguém sabe o que pode está acontecendo? Desde já agradeço a disponibilidade.

MagagedBean:

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScope
public class RegisterUserMB {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    private User user = new User();

    private String confirmPw;

    public String save() {
        userService.addUser(user);
        return "";          
    }
```

Service:

```
@Service
public class UserService {

    @Autowired
    UserRepository<User> userRepository;

    @Transactional
    public boolean addUser(User user) {
        return userRepository.save(user) != null;
    }
```

Repository:

```
public interface UserRepository<U> extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {


}
```

xhtml:

```
<h:form>
                    <h:panelGrid columns="2" style="border:none">
                        <p:inputText id="name" value="#{registerUserMB.profileUser.name}" placeholder="Name"  /> 
                        <p:inputText id="surname" value="#{registerUserMB.profileUser.surname}" placeholder="Surname" />
                    </h:panelGrid>
                    <h:panelGrid>
                        <p:inputText id="mail" value="#{registerUserMB.user.mail}" placeholder="E-mail" size="46" />    
                    </h:panelGrid>
                    <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                        <p:password id="password" value="#{registerUserMB.user.password}" feedback="true" inline="true" placeholder="Password" match="PasswordConf" />
                        <p:password id="PasswordConf" value="#{registerUserMB.confirmPw}"  placeholder="Password confirmation"/>
                        <p:calendar id="brithday" value="#{registerUserMB.profileUser.dateOfBrithday}" placeholder="Brithday" /><h:outputLabel value="" />
                        <p:inputText id="cellphone" value="#{registerUserMB.user.cellphone}" placeholder="Cellphone"/>
                    </h:panelGrid>
                    <p:commandButton value="Save" actionListener="#{registerUserMB.save}"/>
                    </h:form>
```

Obrigado!!

Comment: Linha 27 é `userService.addUser(user);`? `userService` não tá nulo? Tem certeza que esse `RegisterUserMB` é gerenciado e tá no contexto do spring?

Comment: Fala Bruno, consegui resolver, era para o userService ser gerenciado pelo contexto do spring, através da anotação @autoWired, mas para isso acontecer é necessário uma configuração que integre o spring com o JSF, no faces-config.

[https://www.concretepage.com/spring-4/spring-4-jsf-2-integration-example-using-autowired-annotation]

obrigado pela atenção!

Comment: O userService era, que não era é o bean JSF, que é o que falei ali, então obviamente o spring não conseguia injetar a dependência, por que não conhecia RegisterUserMB ;)